# Convert JPG to Video for playback in VLC

Tags: images, vlc-media-player, jpeg

Is this a quick/simple way to convert a bunch of JPG stills into some sort of video file so it can be played back in VLC?  If the convertion can be done using VLC, that would be preferred.

Comment: how about using PowerPoint or Windows Movie Maker ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a **"stopmotion"** maker: here's an [overview](http://www.stopmotionworks.com/stopmosoftwr.htm) of them, and one to download: [CellSoft Take5 1.30](http://take5.cellsoft.qarchive.org/)

Even you can also use Picasa 3 which has a feature that does exactly this - basically, it saves the slideshow into a saved video file - works nicely.

Comment: The link you link to is an ad.

Answer (score 9):

just Open the VLC Player > Media>Convert/save or press ctrl+R >add your images > drop down option to play . Done ! :)

Comment: If you want to then clip the resulting video (it seems to make 9second clips by default) then you might want to specify a different video codec other than H264/5/6. I changed to use MPEG-4 at 30fps and only then could I then clip the video shorter.

Comment: +1 This deserves to be the accepted answer because it meets OP's additional request to do it in VLC itself.

Answer (score 7):

I use mencoder to assemble a series of jpeg frames into an avi, which can then be easily played back in VLC

mencoder mf://*.jpg -mf fps=24 -ovc lavc -lavcopts vcodec=mpeg4:mbd=1:vbitrate=12800:autoaspect=1 -o video.avi

you may want to play with the lavcopts but that should get you going...

ps. I tried to do this with VLC itself but just couldn't figure it out

Comment: It works! Thank you. Could you explain the arguments in details?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows this was the only thing I could get to work with a bunch of non-sequentially named jpegs (e.g. DMC003.JPG, DMC006.JPG, DMC009.JPG)

1. Rename to sequential files in Powershell:

```
dir *.jpg | %{$x=0} {Rename-Item $_ -NewName "Frame$($x.tostring('000000')).jpg"; $x++ }
```

Then in Anaconda prompt:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 15 -i Frame%06d.jpg output.mp4
```

This was using ffmpeg installed with conda:

```
conda create -n ffmpeg -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda activate ffmpeg
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert JPG images to video for playback in VLC, as VLC includes JPG playback. Just add them to the playlist and they'll be shown for 10 seconds.

The JPG playback time is globally adjustable in the settings, or individually by playing around with e.g. an XSPF playlist and the `<vlc:option>image-duration=6</vlc:option>` option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the playback option mentioned above; however like you, I wanted to CONVERT my jpeg files to mp4 using VLC.  So it may be painstaking if you want to convert hundreds of images, but you need to convert each image to mp4 using the CONVERT/SAVE.  Then merge all the newly converted mp4 files into one video.